# Rails - Organizing classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I found quite useful spreading responsibility onto other classes that don't belong to the typical model/controller/view.

I use 'services' folder for anything domain specific and not fitting in the above categories. However, I thought of creating another folder called 'Notifications'. This is the folder structure:

```
app
 -- assets
 -- controllers
 ...
 -- services
 -- notifications
```

First thing I thought of is creating the classes inside Notifications module. 
Something like this:

```
class Notifications::NotSavedPayment

  def self.call payment
   ...
  end

end
```

However, a `NameError: uninitialized constant Notifications` is raised. Which naming/organizing method that works makes more sense here?

Thanks!

Comment: When above mentioned error is raised?

Comment: Have you tried putting this class into app/*some_directory*/notifications/not_saved_payment.rb?

Answer (score 0):

Adding

`config.autoload_paths += [Rails.root.join("app")]`

to

`config/application.rb`

makes this possible.